# Problems with enable_if SFINAE

Tags: c++, sfinae, enable-if

I have been having some inexplicable SFINAE problems in a program I'm writing, so I boiled it down to a freestanding example program:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base { };

struct Derived : public Base { };

template<typename T>
struct From { };

template<typename T>
struct To {
    template<typename U>
    To(const From<U>& other) {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<U*, T*>::value, "error");
    }
};

int main() {
    From<Derived> a;

    To<Base> b = a;
}
```

This program compiles without error or warning. However, this:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base { };

struct Derived : public Base { };

template<typename T>
struct From { };

template<typename T>
struct To {
    template<typename U>
    To(const From<typename std::enable_if<true, U>::type>& other) {
    // this       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<U*, T*>::value, "error");
    }
};

int main() {
    From<Derived> a;

    To<Base> b = a;
}
```

Gives the following error:

> test.cpp: In function `int main()`:
>
> test.cpp:22:18: error: conversion from `From<Base>` to non-scalar type `To<Derived>` requested

Which is because the substitution fails I presume, and the constructor isn't seen.

Am I doing SFINAE wrong, or is this a compiler bug? I am using rubenvb's GCC 4.7.1 on Windows (with `std=c++11` if it makes a difference).

Comment: Clang 3.1 says "candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'U'". I don't think the compiler can deduce `U` in your constructor. How can it be deduced? You are using enable_if to typedef the template type `U`, which you don't know at that point.

Comment: If you do `To<Base> b(a);`, the error message is easier to understand which tells you how the compiler could not deduce `U` from the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a default template argument, that way the argument can be deduced:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base { };

struct Derived : public Base { };

template<typename T>
struct From { };

template<typename T>
struct To {
    template<typename U, class = typename std::enable_if<true, U>::type>
    To(const From<U>& other) {
    // this       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<U*, T*>::value, "error");
    }
};

int main() {
    From<Base> a;

    To<Derived> b = a;
}
```

Note that that causes the `static_assert` to fail since you are using `std::is_convertible` the other way around. It should be:

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<T*, U*>::value, "error");
```

In your example, the template type `U` can't be deduced. In my code, it can be deduced, since it is being used as a template argument for the `other` argument in the constructor. In your code, the compiler sees a `std::enable_if<true, U>::type` and can't deduce what that `U` type is. The fact that the result of that `enable_if` is being used as a template argument for `From` doesn't help at all, since `U` needs to be deduced before that.

Comment: As for the order, actually it's `<from, to>`, not `<to, from>`, so I think mine is correct (and further, the `static_assert` doesn't fail in the first program). I haven't read the rest of the answer yet.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible. The first template argument is `From`. In your code, you'd be saying "Base can be converted to Derived", which is not true.

Comment: Somehow I switched them somewhere because I _know_ I compiled it and it worked fine. Thanks, I'll fix my code to what it originally was.

Comment: Thanks, this was the fix. When exactly does `U` need to be deduced? I don't understand why the compiler doesn't take the first template parameter from the argument and use it as `U`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: The problem is that the compiler sees the call and the template and is left with the problem of matching: `Derived == std::enable_if<true,U>::value`. Now, while you *know* how `enable_if` acts, the compiler does not. To be able to deduce the `U` the compiler would have to instantiate `enable_if<true,X>` for *every type `X`* in the type system. Notes: the set is *infinite*, finding one (i.e. `Derived`) is not sufficient, the compiler would have to prove that there is no other specialization that yields the same type as there could be other specializations that yielded `Derived`

Comment: ... because the problem is intractable, the standard solved it in a simple and direct way: it notes that in that context `U` is not deducible and that the program is ill formed.

Comment: David couldn't explain in better :D.